# How to connect Drools with Mysql using Tomcat7

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, drools-guvnor

I have created a table in side mysql & trying to get table value using drools (means I will send request through drools & get response by mysql)
I downloaded mysql-connector jar & pasted into tomcat lib folder, I am not able to understand that where I have to define database authentication(driver name, driver url, user name, password)
what are the step for establish connection with mysql database,
Please help me any one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the DB in a rule via java function/bean, just look at the tomcat docs:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example